does not install android application
my name is Holman and I am new. I'm making some changes to a mobile app using React-native and also Metro Builder. I start Metro normally, but when I start the application with the command: npm run wharehouse:Android. It should be noted that I am using my personal phone to test it. Everything is normal, when the phone asks me if I want to install the app, I say yes, but the app does not appear anywhere on my phone. I don't know what to do, there are no signs of any error.
I tried restarting my Laptop and Mobile phone, but nothing worked. I hope you can help me solve it and that the application can appear and I can use it to test it.
